# Use Maven assembly plugin to set Linux file permissions for specific files

Tags: java, linux, maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

How to set file permission for specific files using Maven assembly plugin?

The following works ok but it only includes the **specificShFile.sh** in the assembled archive:

```
<assembly>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>specificShFile.sh</include>
            </includes>
            <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
        </fileSet>
        ...
    </fileSets>
    ...
</assembly>
```

What I want is all files to be included in the zip but permission to be set only to that specific file.

Comment: Define another `fileSet` which include all files and exclude the ones for which you want to set the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @SubOptimal for his hint, here is the solution that worked for me:

```
<assembly>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>specificShFile.sh</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>specificShFile.sh</include>
            </includes>
            <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
        </fileSet>
        ...
    </fileSets>
    ...
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 <fileSets>
          <fileSet>
            <useDefaultExcludes/>
            <outputDirectory/>
            <includes/>
            <excludes/>
            <fileMode/>
            <directoryMode/>
            <directory/>
            <lineEnding/>
            <filtered/>
          </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
```

More specific like this

```
<fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <outputDirectory>src/main/java</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
            <fileMode>0644</fileMode>
            <directoryMode>0755</directoryMode>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
```

Comment: @AndredeMiranda fileSets is main hack